# WordPress no stripping of <p>

Tags: wordpress

Can someone tell me how to stop WordPress' TinyMCE from stripping the `<p>` tags?  This is driving me nuts.

I have gone through the entire wp-tinymce.js file trying to find it with no luck.

I cannot use the tinymce-advanced plugin as it breaks something on the site.

Thank you so much if you can help.

EDIT:

I figured it out and posted answer here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/same-old-getting-stripped?replies=2#post-1636991

Answer (score 0):

This [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/) will give you the option to stop TinyMCE from stripping out the

tag.

Comment: "I cannot use the tinymce-advanced plugin as it breaks something on the site."

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively use [this plugin](http://wordpress.ckeditor.com/)